# Sphere in $C^3$ is not compact?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $A=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ is not compact with Euclidean topology?

My attempt — it is not bounded since we can choose $x$ and $y$ to be arbitrarily large and this forces value of $z$ which is in $\mathbb C$ because it is algebraically closed.

Comment: What do you mean by Euclidean topology? This is defined for real spaces, which is not the case here.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Topologically, this *is* a real space: $\mathbb{C}^3\cong\mathbb{R}^6$. (A bit more precisely: the "Euclidean topology" on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is the one gotten by "pulling back" the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ along the obvious bijection.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Understand! Just a naive question... why not just defining the associated quadratic form on $\mathbb R^6$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net No particular reason - depends what feels best, I suppose. (Although I do think it's important to develop comfort with "transporting structure," so I tend to emphasize that approach when reasonable.)

Comment: The set you are analyzing is sometime called “Lie sphere” and the analytic functionals defined on it have been studied extensively by Mitsuo Morimoto and his school.

Comment: The "real" sphere of $\mathbb{C}^3$ would be $\{(z_1, z_2, z_3) \in \mathbb{C}^3: |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 + |z_3|^2= 1\}$. And it corresponds to what you'd get in $\mathbb{R}^6$ which is homeomorphic in a standard way (using real and imaginary parts) to $\mathbb{C}^3$.

Answer (score 4):

That's right! Maybe a slightly cleaner way to say the same argument it would be, "Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, for any $a, b\in\mathbb{C}$ the polynomial $P(z)=a^2+b^2+z^2-1$ has a root; so for every $a, b$ there is some $c$ such that $(a,b,c)\in A$, which means $A$ is not bounded and hence not compact."

*(Depending on what level of detail is wanted, you may also need to justify the conclusion that $A$ is not bounded. But this isn't hard: just show that $A$ contains points arbitrarily far from the origin, and no bounded set contains points arbitrarily far from the origin.)*

A slightly different spin you can put on the same idea is: you've shown that since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, the *projection* of $A$ onto $\mathbb{C}^2$ - the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2: \exists z((x,y,z)\in A)\}$ - is all of $\mathbb{C}^2$, and hence not compact. You can now conclude that $A$ itself is not compact from the following two facts (which are themselves important):

- The projection map $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y)$ is continuous.
- The continuous image of a compact set is always compact *(so contrapositively, if a set has a non-compact set as a continuous image, then the original set is also non-compact)*.

This is overly abstract, certainly, but it's a good "toy example" of how to apply general principles about the behavior of topological properties (in this case, how compactness and continuity interact).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is not bounded. But there is no need to mention $z$ or the fact that $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed. Just note that $A$ contains all vectors of the form $\left(ix,\sqrt{1+x^2},0\right)$, with $x\in\mathbb{R}$. And$$\left\|\left(ix,\sqrt{1+x^2},0\right)\right\|=\sqrt{1+2x^2}.$$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net No, the norm here isn't just the square root of the sum of the squares of the coordinates (that wouldn't always yield a real value - consider e.g. $(1+i,0,0)$). It's the square root of the sum of the squares *of the norms* of the coordinates.